# How to Implement an Android AppWidget in .NET MAUI Blazor?

Tags: c#, android, blazor, android-widget, maui

I am starting my journey into .NET MAUI.
I have some experience working with Blazor which is the reason I chose that.

I have a specific goal in mind as to how my first app should be, which is calling a rest service for some bus stops and then via a widget tells the user how long the user should wait before the next bus arrives.

As I am "comftable" in Blazor I thought I would tackle the widget first with a placeholder view, but I am having some difficulties getting the widget to work, from what I can see in the documentation I should implement the AppWidgetProvider class and override the OnUpdate method, this is what I have so far:

```
public class WidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider
{
        public override void OnEnabled(Context context)
        {
            base.OnEnabled(context);
        }

        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.Length; i++)
            {
                int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Main));
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);


                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, 0);
                views.SetOnClickPendingIntent(0, pendingIntent);

                appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
            }
            base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }
}
```

*I am well aware that this probably does not work, as the ID's I a refering to does not exist.*

After this step I (according to the documentation) should implement the AppWidgetProviderInfo, but every example I have seen of this implementation it's done in XAML.

Does anyone have some examples or at least some guidance to which I can use to move on from this step?

Thanks!

Comment: An Android AppWidget would be defined in your project's `Android folder`. It uses Android `XML`, not Maui `XAML`. Search `xamarin android appwidget` for examples. The c# calls native Android APIs.